# Timer interrupt setup for one second is too slow (~ 4 seconds)

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt

I am trying to use the timer interrupt on an Arduion Uno.

Here is a imple example code for displaying a progressive digit on a lcd display, which is updated with timer interupt every second:

```
#include <LCD_I2C.h>

LCD_I2C lcd(0x27);
volatile bool timerFlag = false; // Timer-Flag (timer-Interrupt)
int displayWidth = 16; // display width
int digit = 0; // current digit

void setup() {
  lcd.begin();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Initializing...");

  noInterrupts();
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS10); // set Prescaler to 1024 
  TCNT1 = 0;
  OCR1A = 15624; // should be 1 second with a prescaler of 102
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A); // Enable timer interrupt
  interrupts();
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
  timerFlag = true;
}

void loop() {
  static int position = 0;
  char displayString[17]; // +1 null termination
  
  if (timerFlag) {
    lcd.clear(); // clear display
    
    // update digit and progress
    digit = (digit + 1) % 10;
    position = (position + 1) % (displayWidth + 1);
    memset(displayString, ' ', displayWidth);
    displayString[displayWidth] = '\0'; add null termination
    displayString[position] = '0' + digit; // Character for the current digit
    
    // Show updated progress on the display
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(displayString);
    
    timerFlag = false;
  }
}
```

The values for setting up he inteupt timer 1 for 1 second is arround everywhere.
BUt the updates generated by this code is clearly much slower than 1 second, it's more about 4 seconds.
So i did a comparison with a delay based version of the same example:

```
#include <LCD_I2C.h>

LCD_I2C lcd(0x27);
int displayWidth = 16; // display width

void setup() {
  lcd.begin();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Initializing...");
}

void loop() {
  for (int digit = 0; digit < 10; digit++) {
    char displayString[17]; // +1 null termination
    int position = digit % (displayWidth + 1);

    // Update progression
    memset(displayString, ' ', displayWidth);
    displayString[displayWidth] = '\0'; // add null termination
    displayString[position] = '0' + digit; // Character for the current digit
    
    // Show updated progress on the display
    lcd.clear(); // Clear display
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(displayString);

    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

This one works as expected and updates every second.

So what is wrong with my interrupt settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a flag in `TCCR1A/B` called `WGM12` which sets the `wave generation mode (WGM)` to `Clear Timer on Compare Match (CTC)`.
This causes the timer to count up to the value in OCR1A and then automatically reset to 0.

This flag was forgotten, so the interrupt simply ignores the setting `OCR1A = 15624;` and counts through to 65535, which corresponds to the observed factor of about 4.
Therefore the setting line for TCCR1B must be changed to

```
TCCR1B = (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS10); 
// Set CTC mode and set Prescaler to 1024
```

Now the interrupt is triggered correctly every second.

Comment: "This still got me some time to find out what it means and what i needed to do, so:" I'm pleased that it was a useful learning exercise for you and your description looks good. Much more valuable than receiving a ready made and complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is ignoring this `OCR1A = 15624;` and simply rolling over at 65535 instead., hence the error factor of 4. You have to set the wave generation mode as CTC in registers TCCR1A/B.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
Unfortunately, I won't be able to try it out until after the weekend.
I will see if it works (but I am pretty confident)

Comment: This still got me some time to find out what it means and what i needed to do, so:
The ctc mode means "Clear Timer on Compare Match" and is controled by the WGM12 flag in the TCCR1A/B register. As I'm using the TCCR1b, the line gets:
`  TCCR1B = (1 << WGM12) | (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS10);`